# React Native function does not fire thru useContext

Tags: react-native, react-context

I am trying to do some conditional renders so I created a boolean called signedIn and tried to change the value from a child component. I spent a lot of time and mostly value came out as read only. Then I was able to find some other example which had setter function passed thru useContext and it worked on the example shown which was a react project. My project is react native and I can not seem to fire the function. I can read the value but cannot change it.
My ContextProvider code is below:

```js
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();
const AuthUpdateContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuthContext() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function useAuthUpdateContext() {
  return useContext(AuthUpdateContext);
}

export function AuthContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(true);
  function toggleSignedIn() {
    setSignedIn((prevSignedIn) => !prevSignedIn);
    console.log("fired from AuthContextProvider : toggleSignedIn");
    console.log(signedIn);
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={signedIn}>
      <AuthUpdateContext.Provider value={toggleSignedIn}>
        {children}
      </AuthUpdateContext.Provider>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Actually it would be nicer to be able to set the value of signedIn prop thru sth like `js setSignedIn(newVal)` but I would settle to get this work as well.
My provider is wrapped around the app as suggested in many places but function does not seem to fire.
This is where I use my function in the signin screen

```js
export default function SignInScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [username, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassWord] = useState("");
  const signedIn = useAuthContext();
  const toggleSignedIn = useAuthUpdateContext();

  const SignIn = async () => {
    try {
      await login(username, password);
      toggleSignedIn;
      console.log("toggleSignedIn fired from SignInScreen");
      console.log(toggleSignedIn);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the toggleSignedIn function as a value in your AuthContextProvider, but you are not using it as a function in your SignInScreen. You are simply referring to it without the brackets instead.use the function:

```
function toggleSignedIn(newVal) {
  setSignedIn(newVal);
}

 const SignIn = async () => {
  try {
    await login(username, password);
    toggleSignedIn(false); // or true, depending on your logic
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried firing the function and it comes out as always true. 
Now I changed it to a bit more controlled function.

```js
  function toggleSignedIn(newVal) {
    setSignedIn(newVal);
``` and console output is like this
```bs

 LOG  before toggleSignedIn fired
 LOG  true
 LOG  fired from AuthContextProvider : toggleSignedIn
 LOG  true
 LOG  after toggleSignedIn fired from SignInScreen
 LOG  true
```

Comment: i update my code check out

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did like your example. However it comes out as all true or all false.. meaning........................................................................................................................
```js
      await login(username, password);
      console.log("before toggleSignedIn fired");
      console.log(signedIn);
      toggleSignedIn(true);
      console.log("after toggleSignedIn fired from SignInScreen");
      console.log(signedIn);
```
All logs are either all true or all false.

Comment: worked or not ....

Comment: I don't know if it worked as I intended to. I cannot say if it's because async firing and timing messes it up or sth else is wrong. I have not implemented conditional firing yet. However it does fire the function so I will accept your answer since the original question was firing the func.

Comment: I was able to track it so that I could actually see it changing in a Text component. Console threw me off sending all true or all false due to async firing. So thanks.. Everything works as intended. Now I'll do the conditional rendering.

Comment: Welcome ! I am pleased that the provided answer works.

Answer (score 0):

I want to post one more answer even though my original question was kindly answered by Pratik Prakash Bindage.

The whole point was I was trying to implement something similar to the [example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) that was explained in the [React Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/)

However I was not getting the result I wanted since my provider was wrapped around the App() functions return statements top level.
Looking like this:

```js
export default function App() {
  const signedIn = useAuthContext();
  console.log("app rendering");
  return (
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <>
            {signedIn ? (
              <>
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="Home"
                  component={HomeScreen}
                  options={{ title: "Lessons" }}
                />
              </>
            ) : (
              <>
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="Login"
                  component={SignInScreen}
                  options={{ title: "Login Screen" }}
                />
              </>
            )}
          </>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContextProvider>
```

This was causing signed in prop not forcing the app to rerender. However when I decided to move my screens into a router component that I created like this...

```js
export default function App() {
  const signedIn = useAuthContext();
  console.log("app rendering");
  return (
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <RouterScreen />
    </AuthContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Everything worked. And, since it was great example at the docs, I am sure a lot of people might be wondering how that works, So I wanted to help out posting my detailed solution.